# What is the function of the PQ307 in this schematic?

Tags: schematics, charger, laptop

I think it's some kind of feedback to the gates of PQ301 and PQ302 but, even so, the voltage at the gates would be equal to the sources and thus, the MOSFETs would be not saturated, right?

I can't understand why is it in the circuit.

[image: Zoomed in]

[image: Whole section]

Comment: Could it work for reverse polarity protection? (VIN < GND)  That's the only way I can imagine Vgs being positive on that transistor.

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks!